# How can I do a unit test to see if angular is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using angular version 1 with jasmine for my unit tests.

The test I want to do is:

When I load the index.html page in ie7 for example I load in a html banner saying download latest browser.

I'm currently loading a html template using JQuery  on the index page.

Is it possible to test this since its outside the angular app.

This is my current code on my index.html page:

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>       
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>      

        <base href="/app/" />

         <!-- Is Angular supported -->  
        <script>
            if(window.angular === undefined)              
                 $(function(){$("#angularNotSupportedModal").load("/app/noAngularModal.html");});
        </script>   

    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-cloak> 
        <div id="angularNotSupportedModal"></div>      

        <div ui-view></div>

        <!-- Application -->
        <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>

        <!-- Config -->
        <script src="/scripts/config.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The task narrows down to good old jQuery testing, which is tedious but possible. It depends on the code if `jQuery` can be just spied or should be totally stubbed and mocked.

The tested script should be isolated to separate function to be tested properly. It may be something like this:

```
it('should call through $ chain', (done) => {
  var angular = window.angular;
  window.angular = undefined;

  spyOn(jQuery.prototype, 'ready').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(jQuery.prototype, 'load').and.callThrough();

  // make spy not break the chain
  var init = jQuery.prototype.init.bind(jQuery.prototype);
  spyOn(jQuery.prototype, 'init').and.callFake(init);

  window.runAngularNotSupportedFunction();

  expect(jQuery.prototype.ready).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function));
  expect(jQuery.prototype.init).toHaveBeenCalledWith('#angularNotSupportedModal', undefined);
  expect(jQuery.prototype.load).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/app/noAngularModal.html');

  window.angular = angular;
  jQuery.ready.promise().done(done)
})
```

Comment: That's the way to test jQuery code. You haven't specified what did you do and why it doesn't work.

Comment: It couldnt find jQuery variable that your using, should I inject it?

Comment: if so how would I do this?

Comment: Yes, you should load jQuery along with Angular in tests.

Comment: This is the git bash error I get when I run the tests: PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Is Angular Supported Tests should call through jquery chain FAILED
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'jQuery.prototype')

Comment: I've added jquery to karma.conf.js

Comment: Jquery seems to be undefined when I test it

Comment: @AngularM It looks like the problem is with Karma configuration and not with the subject. I would suggest to create a new question if you have problems with accessing jQuery in Karma-powered tests.