# How to test controller separately?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, compilation, controller, ng-controller

I have a controller for changing some DOM from different places.

The controller is:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', myController);

function myController() {
    this.addSomeClass = function() {
        $('#idOfSomeElement').addClass('someClass');
    };
}
```

And It is used like this. Inside different components and html.

```
<div id="idOfSomeElement"></div>
.
.
.
<some-angular-component-here>
    <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
        <div ng-click="ctrl.addSomeClass()"></div>
    </div>
</some-angular-component-here>
.
.
.
<using-in-onother-place>
    <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
        <div ng-click="ctrl.addSomeClass()"></div>
    </div>
</using-in-onother-place>
```

I try to test it like this, but I have undefined ctrl.

```
describe('Controller test', function () {
    'use strict';

    var ctrl,
        element;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();
        angular.element('<div id="idOfSomeElement"></div>' +
                        '<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">' +
                            '<div id="button" ng-click="ctrl.addSomeClass()"></div>' +
                        '</div>');

        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$apply();

        // how to get controller here with linked to html?
        ctrl = $controller('myController');
        ctrl = element.controller('myController');

    }));

    it('should add some class', function () {

        var button = $(element).find('#button')[0];
        $(button).trigger('click');

        var someElement = $(element).find('#idOfSomeElement')[0];
        expect(someElement).toHaveSomeClass();
    });
});
```

How to correct test this kind of controller?
And I know that manipulate DOM inside controller it is bad thing but I need to unit test it.

Thanks

Comment: DOM fixtures in tests are detached from the document, so `$('#idOfSomeElement')` selector won't reach the fixture. Your best bet is to mock `$(...)` (most likely can be done by stubbing jQuery `init` method, like it is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36356692/3731501)) and `addClass` method and spy on their calls. This is one of the reasons why mixing jQuery with Angular is bad thing. And yes, this shouldn't be done in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to assign the return value of angular.element to your element property...

```
element = angular.element(....
```

complete beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<div id="idOfSomeElement"></div>' +
                    '<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">' +
                        '<div id="button" ng-click="ctrl.addSomeClass()"></div>' +
                    '</div>');

    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$apply();

    // how to get controller here with linked to html?
    ctrl = $controller('myController');
    ctrl = element.controller('myController');

}));
```