# How would I unit test this simple jQuery code with karma/jasmine?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-webpack

I'm working on creating a webpack starter app for to support lightweight Typescript and jQuery development. So far it's working out well, doing all the cool stuff I want it to do like automatically detecting edits, rebuilding and relaunching the app when you change things, etc. It supports unit and e2e testing as well.

But I've never unit tested jQuery code, and I don't even know where to begin to test this dead-simple "Hello, world!" app:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

export interface SampleInterface {
  stuff: string;
}

$('#message').text('Hello, world!');
```

What would a unit test that ensures that this message has been set look like?

I've installed `karma-jquery` and `karma-jasmine-jquery`. I've googled a lot looking for examples of how to use these tools, but none of what I've seen matches the simple problem I'm trying to solve.

**UPDATE:**

I think I'm getting closer to what I want to do with the following test that doesn't quite work:

```
describe('main', () => {
  it('should say hello', () => {
    spyOn(jQuery.prototype, 'text').and.callThrough();
    require('./main');
    expect(jQuery.prototype.text).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Hello, world!');
  });
});
```

It doesn't surprise me that this doesn't work, because this spies on a jQuery prototype method, whereas what I think I need to be spying on is a particular jQuery object, but how to create that and spy on it so that it works with the selector `#message`, I haven't got a clue yet.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36356692/3731501

Comment: @estus, that example helped some, but I'm still not sure how to test this specific case. Am I going to have to wrap `$('#message').text('Hello, world!');` in a function just so I can call it separately to test it?

Comment: Yes, it's preferable, but if it's not wrapped in original app, it won't be wrapped. In this case you need to spy on $ before tested file will be imported, so you need to import it not with `import` but with `require('.../app')` inside a test.

Comment: I'm trying `require('./main')`, which my editor is happy with and even auto-completes for me, but when I try to run the test, I'm getting `Error: Cannot find module "./main"`.

Comment: I got passed the problem of not finding the module, and now have a test that runs but fails, which I'll add as an update to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally stumbled into creating a test that works:

```
describe('main', () => {
  let jqdiv;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', 'message');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    jqdiv = $(div);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jqdiv.remove();
  });

  it('should say hello', () => {
    require('./main');
    expect(jqdiv.text()).toBe('Hello, world!');
  });
});
```

**Update**:

Improved test so that it cleans up after itself.